# GCP Cloud Composer 2.1.15, getting Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number during DAG parsing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-composer

DAG is in broken status since the time we have moved to `Composer version 2.1.15` and Airflow 2.4.3
Previously with `composer version 2.1.11` and Airflow 2.4.3, `did not see any issue of context.py`

Note: Airflow version is same as previous version however composer version has changed causing this issue

[image]

Using `pyspark version : 3.0.1`

I have gone through SO linked talking about fixing `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`.
We do not have control over such changes in cloud. Hence, am not understanding where to fix this as we are running codes using `DataprocClusterOperator`(Airflow).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated some internal cases and I found that `composer-2.1.15-airflow-2.4.3` has a running DAG as long as you have a compatible instance. Your error can be resolved by setting `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` with master:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[3] pyspark-shell"
source ~/.bashrc
```

You can also check the installation of `Java` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Reinstall/install Java:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Then, set the JAVA_HOME:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing  the `install-jdk==0.3.0` under the PyPI tab in composer airflow, solved the issue